# Only perform jquery effects/operations on certain pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

Up until now i've been dropping all my jquery code right inside the document.ready function. I'm thinking that for certain situations this isnt the best way to go.

for example: If i want an animation to perform when a certain page loads what is the best way to go about that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element_1").fadeIn();
    $("#element_2").delay('100').fadeIn();
    $("#element_3").delay('200').fadeIn();
});
```

If this is right inside of document.ready then every time **ANY** page loads it's going to check each line and look for that element. What is the best way to tell jquery to only perform a chunk of code on a certain page to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

by checking if elememt exist on the page before execute animation

```
if ($("#element-1").length) { 
   $("#element-1").fadeIn();
}
```

and so on with other elements `#element_2` and `#element_3`

---

to @numediaweb:

current jQuery `is()` implementation is like below

```
is: function( selector ) {
  return !!selector && jQuery.filter( selector, this ).length > 0;
 },
```

so, it can be smarter to use `is()` but it is faster to use just `length` and even faster to sue `document.getElementById().length`

Comment: So to avoid repetition i could just have a unique id for each page's body element and check if that exists!

Comment: A better approach is to [Set a class attribute to your body tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578348/best-way-to-execute-js-only-on-specific-page/9578898#9578898)

Answer (score 0):

Only include the code you *want* to be executed when the DOM is ready for that particular page. `$(document).ready(...` does not mean that you should have the same chunk of code run on each page. That would necessitate performing various checks in order to know what needs to be executed.

I'm sure that you will have some common functionality that you would want to execute on each page, as well as some page-specific functionality. If that is the case, then you could put the common functionality into a single function, and call it from the `$(document).ready(...` such that the only remaining code is specific to that particular page. For example:

```
function common() {
    alert('hello');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    common();
    // do some page-specific stuff
});
```

I disagree with performing various checks on every single page so the code knows where we're at. It seems cumbersome and totally avoidable, for instance:

```
function doAnimation() {
    $("#element_1").fadeIn();
    $("#element_2").delay('100').fadeIn();
    $("#element_3").delay('200').fadeIn();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href == 'http://example.com/foo') {
        doAnimation();
    }
    if(this page has blah) {
        doBlah();
    }
});
```

Ideally, what it *should* be is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do stuff for foo.php
});
```

Comment: are you suggesting having different js files for each page?

Comment: @Galen - yes, somewhat. I am trying to encourage you to only use code where it is needed, rather than putting conditionals in to find out if it needs to execute.