# How To load js only in one page of my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, turbolinks, sprockets

I'm trying to load a js file into a single page of my app. But it is called in all and this ends up generating errors on my screen.

My application.js is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

My application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Netshow</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column'>
      <header class='masthead mb-auto'>
        <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
      </header>
      <%= yield %>
      <footer class='mastfoot mt-auto'>
        <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My js file is:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  console.log('teste')
  var player = videojs('my_video_1');

  var options = {};

  player.on('play', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:"/video_clicks/",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        video_click: { video_id: window.location.pathname.split('/')[2] }
      },
      success: function(){
        $('span.video-count')[0].innerText = parseInt($('span.video-count')[0].innerText) + 1
      }
    });
  });

  function showCount(){
    var id = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2] 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url:"/video_clicks/"+id,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        console.log($('span.video-count')[0])
        $('span.video-count')[0].innerText = data
      }
    });
  }

  showCount()
});
```

I would like to load the js file only on one page of my app and not at all. How can I do this? I have already tried removing the require_tree add content in application.html.erb and set the content in my html file, but the rails speaks that I have to add the file in assets.erb for precompilation and when I do this the other pages reload my js file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to execute js only on specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578348/best-way-to-execute-js-only-on-specific-page)

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options in that scenario:

1. You can check the `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]` in **application.html.erb**, if that matches the specific page controller+action then only load the JS. (Better Solution)

Like:

```
<% if params[:controller] == 'your_controller_name' && params[:action] == 'your_action_name' %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/custom_js' %>
<% end %>
```

Based on this code above, I'll create a new file named `custom_js.html.erb` in my **views > shared** folder. Then write the script in that file inside `<script></script>` tag. Also, you need to remove that script file from `application.js` file.

2. You can create a different layout for that specific page access method. Like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025784/rails-layouts-per-action#answer-3025806).

Comment: hum...how i can check the params controller and action in application.html.erb?

Answer (score 0):

You just simply include that page (erb file) with `<%= javascript_include_tag 'js_file_name' %>`

Answer (score 0):

Add to you view and

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'js_file_name' %>
```

config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(js_file_name.js)
```