# How can I add a js script to an html web page and not have it apply to subpages?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a service, breezy.hr for hiring, and they don't give me access to the HTML, they only let me add js to a script in their GUI and it shows up in the website code as below, towards the end of the body.

```
<script>
document.title = 'Hiring - Eastern Union';
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[7].innerHTML = "<a href='/p/2066e45ed47a-commercial-real-estate-mortgage-broker/apply'><button class='button apply polygot button-right bzyButtonColor'>Apply</button><h2>Commercial Real Estate Mortgage Broker</h2><ul class='meta'><li class='location'><i class='fa fa-wifi'></i><span class='polygot'>Remote OK</span></li><li class='type'><i class='fa fa-building'></i><span class='polygot'>Full-Time</span></li><li class='department'><i class='fa fa-building'></i><span>Multi-Family Group</span></li></ul><button class='button apply polygot button-full bzyButtonColor'>Apply</button><\a>";
</script>
```

The problem is that when I use the inner.html command to edit the HTML, it applies to subpages, which have different elements, and it therefor ruins the subpage. Is there a way to limit the edits to the parent page, as well as apply things just to the subpage?
(excuse my terminology, I'm not trained in HTML or js, I've just been using it for this one project)

Comment: does checking the url of the page work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to execute js only on specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578348/best-way-to-execute-js-only-on-specific-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple `if` statement, you can edit the home page else the sub pages.

```
<script>

if(window.location == "Your home page url"){

document.title = 'Hiring - Eastern Union';
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[7].innerHTML = "<a href='/p/2066e45ed47a-commercial-real-estate-mortgage-broker/apply'><button class='button apply polygot button-right bzyButtonColor'>Apply</button><h2>Commercial Real Estate Mortgage Broker</h2><ul class='meta'><li class='location'><i class='fa fa-wifi'></i><span class='polygot'>Remote OK</span></li><li class='type'><i class='fa fa-building'></i><span class='polygot'>Full-Time</span></li><li class='department'><i class='fa fa-building'></i><span>Multi-Family Group</span></li></ul><button class='button apply polygot button-full bzyButtonColor'>Apply</button><\a>";
}
else{
console.log("sub page");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! what is the else doing?

Comment: @Antheloth,if matches the statement, and when that doesn't match, it runs whatever is in the else function. I have console.log in the else statement just to show that it is a sub page, but that is where you will want to add the scripts for the sub pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access `window.location` and tell the script to run only if it's the main page.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: tell the script to log/alert the location and see the differences between main page and sub pages, and test for that when you revise the script.

Comment: You can see someone copied my answer and elaborated on that...  :)